# F# serialization: Field in TypedReferences cannot be static or init only

Tags: f#, binaryformatter

I am trying to serialize a data structure, that involves a couple of discriminated unions and records. At some moment, to improve performance (its a scientific computing project), I tried to change some of the types participating in the structure to be .NET structs. However, in one particular case that broke my checkpoints, that are based on `BinaryFormatter`.

After adding `[<Struct>]` to one of my records, they started failing serialization roundtrip with the following message on deserialize: Field in TypedReferences cannot be static or init only.

Since, I was only able to find a suggestion to add `[<CLIMutable>]` to that record, so that its fields are no longer `readonly`. However, unexpectedly, that did not help.

I managed to narrow the example down to this:

```
module BinSerializer =
    type Node = Leaf | Node of Node * Node

    [<Struct>]
    [<CLIMutable>] 
    type Struct = { Term: byte; Node: Node }

    type Uni = A | B | S of Struct

    open System.IO
    open System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

    let fail() =
        let formatter = BinaryFormatter()
        use stream = new MemoryStream()
        formatter.Serialize(stream, S({ Term = 0uy; Node = Leaf }))
        stream.Flush()
        stream.Position <- 0L
        formatter.Deserialize(stream) |> ignore


BinSerializer.fail()
```

Removing `[<Struct>]` lets the call succeed. Removing `Node` field from `Struct` too.

F# 4.1 targeting .NET 4.7.1 + FSharp.Core 4.4.3